# Window freezes if there are many records in ListView which added from threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, listview, delphi-xe

My program do the "heavy" task (searching files and finding a signature) on a separated thread. Every task uses PostMessage to call a procedure for adding a record into a ListView.

The problem is when ListView (often) displays  many records, my window will freeze. It seems my program is screaming to request Application.ProcessMessages. Only the Progressbar is still moving. After the operation has finished, everything back to normal.

If I remove the operation for adding record, the operation of my program will run smoothly.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We once hit the limit of how many messages can be posted to the message queue. Most likely you are hitting this limit as well.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> There is a limit of 10,000 posted
>   messages per message queue. This limit
>   should be sufficiently large. If your
>   application exceeds the limit, it
>   should be redesigned to avoid
>   consuming so many system resources.

From [The Best Synchronization is No Synchronization](http://www.flounder.com/no_synchronization.htm)

> The problem with PostMessage to the main GUI thread is that you can
>   "saturate" the main GUI message pump,
>   and interfere with WM_TIMER and
>   WM_PAINT messages (these messages are
>   only dispatched if the message queue
>   is empty, and PostMessage means that
>   the queue might never be empty.  In
>   addition, there is a nominal limit of
>   10,000 messages in the input queue;
>   after that, PostMessage will discard
>   the message and return FALSE.  In
>   addition, even if the 10,000 limit is
>   not hit, even a few hundred messages
>   can mean that the user sees poor
>   response to keyboard and mouse input,
>   an unacceptable situation.

Comment: I still have no idea after reading your answer. I know I am just a beginner and I think I want to try Synchronize. Let's see the result.

Comment: @user, Synchronize is most likely the worst "solution" you could try. What worked for us was to simply trim down on when messages got posted. In the end, all the main thread needed to know was there was "some" change. Posting every 1000th message for instance (messagecount mod 1000 = 0) could be all it takes and still have a smooth progress. Offcourse, make sure that your last notification does get posted.

Comment: If that does not work for you, you'll have to resort to other synchronization techniques like the ones described in the Synchronization link.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with many items, it might be worth to change the overall structure of your program.

Instead of filling the list view, try filling some other data structure and then make another thread make the windows updates and use `SendMessage`. That way your worker threads are not stalled and you don't flood your message queue. On the other hand this would require a lot more synchronizing between the threads.

Another way would be to use some control with virtual items, such as [VirtualTreeview](http://www.delphi-gems.com/VirtualTreeview/)  (which can be configured to behave like a list view) That way you can fill your backing data structure and the control *asks* for the data as soon as an item is scrolled into view. Because even with millions of items, only a few are visible at a time, this might give you a huge boost in speed, because filling the control now is only a matter of setting the total number of items.

Comment: You don't need to switch to a different component to use virtual mode. Plain TListView handles that.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'm using VirtualTreeview for all my lists or trees since forever. I guess I'm a little behind with the standard controls :)

Comment: Windows list view has been able to do that since forever also! Virtual Treeview is great, but I like the native feel of TListView, especially when you call SetWindowsTheme(..., 'explorer') on it.

Comment: @DR, if I use SendMessage then I get Not Responding window. MadExcept show "The application seems to be frozen". The error line is on my procedure that adding item.

Comment: @user: You have to use SendMessage from a *single* thread. If each of your worker threads uses SendMessage, eventually all of them will be blocked. (Because of the same underlying reason @Lieven pointed out and because SendMessage does not return until the operation is completed)

Comment: @David Virtual Treeview has option to set Windows theme automatically.

Comment: @DR, Okay now I use SendMessage and I only use single thread. It works! Thanks. But I don't want to use a single thread :)

Comment: @Linas I bet it uses owner draw though rather than system paint. Or am I out of date?

Comment: @David No, it calls SetWindowTheme. It looks the same as native treeview or listview.

Comment: @user: You still can have multiple worker threads, but they have to make their list view update requests not by calling Send/PostMessage themselves, but by relaying the request to a single list view updater thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a virtual grid control, like the [ExGridView](http://www.flex-graphics.com/Files/Free/GridView.zip) from roman mochalov, or Mike Lishke's very popular Virtual Tree View (Delphi Gems).  When new content arrives, merely set a flag, and then decide how often you want to refresh the screen, and refresh asynchronously, but not once per new item that comes in.

One refresh per 200 mSec will be all most users can stand to see, anyways.